# Passing Dynamic code to MySQL execute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing some reports code, which requires executing complex sql code and executing this using raw connection. I am good for the static paramteres but not sure how to handle the dynamic values.

I prepare the dynamic sql and then create a statement object

```
st = conn.prepare(dynamic_sql_string)
st.execute(dynamic values).
```

How do I create this dynamic values code?
In one it will be

```
st.execute(@first_name)
```

and in second case it will be

```
st.execute(@last_name).
```

How do I write this dynamic code?

Answer (score 1):

Got it, you do this using

```
eval "st.execute(dynamic values").
```